# Does setInterval store expression value/code given to execute?

Tags: javascript, browser

When we execute `setInterval` with function variables in the console and after this, we change the function variable definition. Even now the old code is getting executed in setInterval. **Does setInterval store old value...?**

```
var funA = function(){document.write("Hello</br>");};
setInterval(funA,1000);
```

After running above code in the console `Hello` is getting written in the document. After some time I run the following code:

```
var funA = function(){document.write("Bye</br>");};
```

But still, I am getting `Hello` being written in the document even though the definition of function `funA` is changed.

Another observation is that if I re-execute the `setInterval` then I start to get `Bye` too.

```
setInterval(funA,1000);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You merely assigned a new function to the same variable name. `setInterval` still has the reference to the previous function.

Comment: But where is the previous reference stored and when I assigned the new function to the same variable then it should be over-writing the same memory (or not)?

Comment: no, it doesn't overwrite anything ... you stop an interval using `clearInterval`

Comment: The reference to `funA` is stored in the call stack of the function call to `setInterval`.  At that point, you can't "update" the value - it's outside your scope.

Comment: Thanks @PaulProgrammer , I think I am getting it now.

Comment: @ShivamSharma The function is stored somewhere in the heap (memory) that you don’t have access to.

Answer (score 1):

It's not "context" that is being stored, but rather the reference to the function that had been the initial definition of `funA`. If you wanted to dynamically change the function, you'll have to create a [trampoline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_(computing)).

```
var funA = function() {document.write("Hello</br>");};
var funB = function() {document.write("Bye");};
var myTrampoline = {target: funA};

function callTrampoline() {return myTrampoline.target();};
setInterval(callTrampoline,1000);
myTrampoline.target=funB;
```

Now, the second function would be called, because you've updated the reference.